# Refactoring bad code switch statment without distort everything

Tags: object-oriented, php, refactoring, anti-patterns, switch-statement

Once in a while I’m stumbling on switch statements during a 
Code Review session.

I would like to find a more elegant way of this code

....

```
$istannceOfClass = $repository->loadFoo(); 
switch($istannceOfClass) 
{  
    case $istannceOfClass instanceOf derivedClassAB:
        $istannceOfClass->callA(); 
        $istannceOfClass->callB(); 
        break;
    case $istannceOfClass instanceOf derivedClassCD:
        $istannceOfClass->callC(); 
        $istannceOfClass->callD(); 
        break;
    case $istannceOfClass instanceOf derivedClassEF:
        $istannceOfClass->callE(); 
        $istannceOfClass->callF(); 
        break;
}
```

I thought about improve the code. could the anonymous class be used?
I can not change the hierarchy and subclasses of $istannceOfClass and $istannceOfClass itself.

an attempt: to improve, correct, throw
I used anonymouse for convenience.
Code that can not be changed

```
interface baseclass { }

class ab implements baseclass 
{
    public function callA()
    {
        return "<br>class ab Call A";

    } 

    public function callB()
    {
        return "<br>class ab Call B";
    } 
}

class cd implements baseclass 
{
    public function callC()
    {
        return "<br>class cd Call B";

    } 

    public function callD()
    {
        return "<br>class cd Call C";
    } 
}
```

New code for refactor 
first common interface with all methods

```
interface commonABCDEF 
{
    public function callA(); 
    public function callB();
    public function callC(); 
    public function callD();
    public function callE(); 
}
```

second abstract class for default behaviour

```
class abstractCommonAbcdef implements commonABCDEF
{    
    //common behavior
    public function callA() { return '<br>default A'; }
    public function callB() { return '<br>default B'; }
    public function callC() { return '<br>default C'; }
    public function callD() { return '<br>default D'; }
    public function callE() { return '<br>default E'; }
    //abstract public function run(); 

}
```

adapter for case 1 of switch

```
$abOverride = new class(new ab()) extends abstractCommonAbcdef 
{   
    public function __construct(baseclass $abcde)
    {
        $this->abcde = $abcde;
    }     

    public function callA() 
    {
        return $this->abcde->callA(); 
    }

    public function callB() 
    {
    return $this->abcde->callB(); 
    }

    public function run()
    {

    } 
};
```

....

final call al method

```
$rightClass = new class($abOverride)
{
    public function __construct(abstractCommonAbcdef $abcommonABCDEF) 
    {
        $this->abcommonABCDEF = $abcommonABCDEF; 
    }

    public function getBo() {
        return $this->abcommonABCDEF;
    }
};


echo $rightClass->getBo()->callA(); 
echo $rightClass->getBo()->callB(); 
echo $rightClass->getBo()->callC(); 
echo $rightClass->getBo()->callD();
```

Comment: $class is a apparently a reference to an object, not the name of a class. I think it would be good to rename it to $object.

Comment: Can you add an interface implementation to classAB, classCD and classEF or is there a reason you want to avoid editing them?

Comment: You cannot change the classes, it calls for a virtual method though.

Comment: @bdsl technical problem, too long to explain...

Comment: If these ABC methods don't take parameters it should be easy to wrap the response from $repository into common interface (repository itself can implement some contract this way) - even with single method. Parameters change everything. Anyway, I wouldn't expect detailed answer here, because while concrete problem might have abstract solution (many implementations that lead to expected outcome), concrete solution to abstract problem does not exist.

Answer (score 9):

You can make a new interface and have all three classes implement it.

Each one will implement the same method but with a different implementation.

The switch statement can then be replaced with a call to that method.

Martin Fowler calls this refactoring [Replace Conditional With Polymorphism](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html). In his example he introduces an abstract superclass rather than an interface. It could work either way, but I tend to prefer interfaces.

Comment: I also thought this solution I like it.
other ideas ?

Comment: @ CandiedOrange right! done!

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow thank you. Now please delete these comments that are no longer meaningful because of the edit.